# split a matrix based on values of a column

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to split a matrix e.g.,

```
mat={{a1,b1,c1,1},{a2,b2,c2,1},{a3,b3,c3,2},{a4,b4,c4,2}}
```

into two matrices based on the last (or any) column (in this case, the last column has value 1 or 2):

```
mat1={{a1,b1,c1,1},{a2,b2,c2,1}} 
mat2={{a3,b3,c3,2},{a4,b4,c4,2}}
```

the `mat1, mat2` should be generated according to available values of the "sorting column".

Any simple/efficient solutions ?

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer `GroupBy` over `GatherBy`. `GatherBy` uses the ordering of occurrence of the keys in the matrix `m` which need not coincide with the natural order of the keys. `GroupBy` uses the same ordering as `GatherBy` but also utilizes `Association` to store the keys which makes it easier to access data. Here is an example for keys in the second column where the natural ordering gets mixed up.

```
SeedRandom[0];
m = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {5, 5}];
a = GatherBy[m, #[[2]] &]
b = GroupBy[m, #[[2]] &]
a == Values[b]

(* {{{3, 3, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 1, 3, 1}}, {{3, 1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 3, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2, 3, 1}}} *)
(* <|3 -> {{3, 3, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 1, 3, 1}}, 1 -> {{3, 1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 3, 2}}, 2 -> {{2, 2, 2, 3, 1}}|> *)
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Note, from the documentation, that `SplitBy`

> splits list into sublists consisting of **runs of successive elements** that give the same value when f is applied.

So while `SplitBy` will work in the case you give, it may not be very robust if you can't always guarantee that your original matrix will contain "runs of successive elements". With that in mind, `GatherBy` might be the way to go. For `mat` as in the example you give, `SplitBy` and `GatherBy` give the same answer:

```
SplitBy[mat, Last] === GatherBy[mat, Last]

(* True *)
```

But suppose the rows of `mat` are mixed (say, switch rows 2 and 3) up so that the last entries are not sequential:

```
mixmat = {{a1, b1, c1, 1}, {a3, b3, c3, 2}, {a2, b2, c2, 1}, {a4, b4, c4, 2}};
```

Then `SplitBy` gives four sublists, each containing a single row, but `GatherBy` still gets the right result.

```
SplitBy[mixmat , Last]
GatherBy[mixmat , Last]

(* {{{a1, b1, c1, 1}}, {{a3, b3, c3, 2}}, {{a2, b2, c2, 1}}, {{a4, b4, c4, 2}}}

(* {{{a1, b1, c1, 1}, {a2, b2, c2, 1}}, {{a3, b3, c3, 2}, {a4, b4, c4, 2}}} *)
```

To form matrices based on the value of other rows, you can do, for example:

```
SeedRandom[0]; m = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {4, 4}];
GatherBy[m, #[[2]] &]

(* {{{3, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 1}}, {{3, 1, 2, 2}}} *)
```

which generates matrices based on the second entry in each row.

Comment: thanks point out the successive element.